# Dual Monitor Setup with Ati Radeon Hd 5700 results in unusabledesktop win7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, graphics

I have an ATI Radeon HD 5700 card which i've been using under fully updated windows 7 with its latest drivers.

My monitor is a 2004 NEC LCD1703M which despite being pretty old runs fine.
A friend gave me an IIYAMA ProLite E1900WS monitor (2009 or 20010 ).
Both monitors are vga only.
I've been using a DLDVI to VGA adapter to connect my old monitor and tested the same adapter to the new monitor and it worked fine.

So I bought an HDMI to vga adapter with the purpose of having a dual monitor setup.
But when both screens are connected to the card the following problem occurs:
The monitor connected to the hdmi port cycles between sleep and a black screen while the other shows the operating system for about two seconds before getting black for another two seconds. I can "use" the computer (move the mouse,click,type e.t.c.) while this happens but its not something pleasant.

I tried reinstalling the driver, booting with both screens connected (in which case the powerup messages and the bios are mirrored in both screens until I get to the login screen where everything falls apart)

Funny thing is, everything works if I disconnect the ATI graphics card and use the onboard intel one.

So, any suggestions as to what might be the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: Lol, super late edit.  either way if he still has the card and still cant use dual monitors, this card should support 3 video outputs http://graphics-cards.specout.com/l/54/ATI-HD-5700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the card does not support dual analog display.
So when i use two monitors I connect them in the onboard card and choose it over the ati
and when i want high quality graphics (gaming,movies,e.t.c.) I just disconnect one monitor and use the ati

Answer (score 1):

## Drivers, OS Config, or Available Power

To start with the long shot first; is there any chance that your system's power supply is under-rated to drive the hardware that you have installed?  This is a long shot, but is not out of the realm of possibility.

### When You Say "Reinstalling the Driver"

Are you using [ATI's driver(s)](http://support.amd.com/US/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx) or are you letting the M$ update search for a driver to use?  You should be doing the former.  Personally, I do not let the driver bundles run and install all the *extra* stuff they get bundled with.  You can often use an archive utility like 7-zip or WinRar to unpack the OEM driver bundle and then just let the driver update dialog search through the extracted files to identify the appropriate driver it wants/needs.

I do it that way because I want to avoid all the extra manager apps that the bundle installs.  They would be running in your tray if you already installed the whole bundle.  Do you have a restore point that you can go back to?

### OS Configuration

One more long shot.  Have you tried cycling through the FN+F6 or F7 settings.  One of those key combinations usually cycles through the projector settings.

I'm assuming that your video card, OS, and the "new driver" that you downloaded are all in agreement about the platforms they support.  Make sure the OS updates, in general, are applied.  Reboot and investigate the monitor configuration from your Control Panel.

I have to run now, sorry.  If that initial run through didn't highlight the issue, then I would ask you some questions about your VGA/HDMI adapter and configuration.

Good luck!

Comment: i checked all of your list and it didnt work, although its a pretty goog checklist for graphic card troubleshooting thank you :-)